# Multidimensional array to multidimensional tuple

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array, tuples

If I have an array such:

```
inner_loop = 
[
 [
  [18, 119], [42, 119], [42, 95], [18, 95]
 ],
 [
  [80, 96], [80, 75], [59, 75], [59, 96]
 ]
]
```

how do I convert it to a multidimensional tuple like

```
(
 (
  (18, 119), (42, 119), (42, 95), (18, 95)
 ),
 (
  (80, 96), (80, 75), (59, 75), (59, 96)
 )
)
```

I have tried:

```
tuple(tuple(y) for y in (tuple(tuple (x) for x in (tuple(inner_loops)))))
```

but the last level is not converted.

Comment: I am using an external library that requires it.

Comment: How many levels are potentially there?

Comment: No more than 3. It's a list of polygons, so list -> polygons -> vertices

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
tuple(tuple(tuple(l2) for l2 in l1) for l1 in inner_loop)
```

Answer (score 4):

Using map is a bit more readable and actually more efficient if you have large amounts of data:

```
inner_loop = tuple(tuple(map(tuple, sub)) for sub in inner_loop)

print(inner_loop)
(((18, 119), (42, 119), (42, 95), (18, 95)), ((80, 96), (80, 75), (59, 75), (59, 96)))
```